# ArcSDK.h Not Found in Default Path

Tags: visual-c++, arcgis, lidar

By default, it should be at ..\include\CPPAPI. But on my machine this folder doesn't even exist, only 'CatIDs' and 'GridIDs' folders reside in \include. I've installed ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 and its VC++ SDK.

I am new to ArcGIS and LiDAR, I've got LAS file and corresponding text version, all I need to do is to convert txt file to shp file. I found one example code that can do this, it included ArcSDK.h.

Thank any of you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to install the ArcGIS Engine C++ Dev Kit (ArcGIS Engine SDK
for Cross Platform C++) described at http://wikis.esri.com/wiki/display/ag93bsr/ArcGIS+Engine#ArcGISEngine-DeveloperSolutions%28SDK%29Requirements. I don't use the VC++ Dev kit so I'm not sure if it includes the ArcSDK.h file. However, if you install ArcEngine Runtime and the ArcEngine SDK for cross platform C++, the ArcSDK file will be in ArcGIS\include\CPPAPI as you noted.